# get time in millisecond in find command linux

Tags: linux, kernel

I am executing following command of `find` in linux. `find /Volumes/app -user john -mtime 60`. It gives the list of file modified.

After adding `-printf '%TY %Tb %Td %TH:%TM %p\n'` in `find` command in gives list of files with date.

Following is the output:

```
2022 Nov 28 19:05 .
2022 Nov 28 18:31 ./abc.py
```

But instead of date How to get time in milliseconds?

Comment: milliseconds since when?

Comment: So how can we convert `2022 Nov 28 18:31` in millisecond from the output of `find` command

Answer (score 0):

`date +%s%N` returns the number of seconds + current nanoseconds.

Try this

> **-printf $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))**

`date +%s` returns the number of seconds since the epoch, if that's useful.

Comment: `find /Volumes/app -user john -mtime 0 -printf $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))` it is giving only the time but not the filenames

Answer (score 0):

This gives time in nano-seconds by GNU find :

```
find . -printf '%TY %Tb %Td .%TT %p\n'
```

Comment: 2022 Nov 29 .09:34:43.5978567650 abc/

2022 Nov 28 .20:56:07.2236949700 abc/data.py

2022 Nov 29 .09:34:43.5978567650 abc/bac.py

2022 Nov 28 .18:31:15.8937388620 abc/abc.py

following is the format of output

Comment: You just need to round nano-seconds to milli-seconds